# How can you find the documentation for all derived types in Xcode documentation browser

Tags: xcode, documentation

Say I'm learning about the UIGestureRecognizer class. In the intro text it mentions UITapGestureRecognizer and UIRotationGestureRecognizer as two concrete implementations. But what other recognizers are there? This is just one example where I'd like to see a list of all the types in the framework that derive from a base class or implement a protocol. In the .NET docs, Microsoft provides a link to all known derived types in the SDK. Is something like this available from Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an open project, you can go to the `Class Browser` in the Project menu.  It will show you the entire class hierarchy or all the classes in a flat list.

As a shortcut for your own classes, you can click on the **`C`** in the top right corner of a source or header file.  It will show a summary of the view hierarchy for that class, if the source is in the project.

Here is a small [hierarchy](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/uikit_framework/Introduction/Introduction.html) that happens to include the gesture recognizers and some other common classes.  Scroll down to the bottom.